# Tkinter result page with possible cyclic dependency

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, python-class

I'm having trouble creating a results page for a tkinter GUI that I've made. The problem is that the `page2` file has to import the `page3` file in order to go to `page3` when clicked with a button. In the meantime, I also need the input from `page2` on `page3` (making it a results page).  I've tried to solve this by defining a function that can push the variable from `page2` and am able to get that on `page3` but I cannot get it to actually show on the window.

To complicate things a bit, I've been working from different files and in classes. It sounds very much like circular dependency but I've been able to do create a (other) try-out working model when not operating in classes. This is the MWE:

`page1`

just an operating page to smoohtly transition from one window to another (disregard this as it should be working fine)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

from page2 import *

######Ensuring that the frames don't load as seperate windows but as frames over one another#######

class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # create a container for all the widgets (buttons, etc)
        window = Frame(self)
        window.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        # for loops for switching between pages
        for F in (Page2, Page3):
            frame = F(window, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Page2)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = GUI()
    window.geometry("400x400")
    window.mainloop()
```

`page2`

input window for the results page

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import page3
from page3 import *

class Page2(Frame):
          
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        DF = Listbox(self, bg='red',height=30, width=70, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
        DF.place(x=0, y=0) 
      
        button = Button(
            DF, 
            text="press",
            bg='#ffffff', 
            height=4, 
            width=30,
            command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(page3.Page3), Page2.get_values(self)],
              )
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        
        
        self.entry = Entry(self, fg="black", justify=CENTER)
        self.entry.insert(0, 'Entry ')
        self.entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
        
        
    def get_values(self, event=None):
        from page3 import Page3
        my_entry = self.entry.get()
        page3.Page3.show_values(my_entry)
```

`page3`

output page with the results from the input entry

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Page3(Frame):
    
    value_from_page2= None
    
    def show_values(value):
        global value_from_p1
        value_from_page2= value
        print(value)
        print(value_from_page2)
    
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        DF2 = Listbox(self, bg='blue', height=30, width=70)
        DF2.place(x=0, y=0) 
        Label_value = Label(self, text = self.value_from_page2)
        Label_value.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

I have tried different manners of getting to the wanted result based on similar issues reported on stackoverflow, but I am getting an error for every code I tried. This is my closest code to the wanted outcome. The wanted result is that where it now says `self.value_from_page2`, it should be the entry value inserted on `page2`. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In Page1 add this from page2 import *
from page3 import *

Comment: line 30, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[cont]
            ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^  When I press button.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I've tried the double import which didn't change the outcome unfortunately. I did find that I deleted one line to much, in page 2 there should be "from page3 import *". I changed it now in the code of page 2. I'm not getting the show_frame error you describe above with the same code

Comment: Actually, you got button working, That fine with u.

Comment: Ok! When I pressed button. I can see blue window with Label widget but cannot see Listbox widget.

Comment: I can see Listbox widget widget to workaround . On page3 can you do layout manage for bouth Label and Listbox? You had this place(x=0, y=0) and place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5,. The Listbox is out of window.

Comment: The listbox widget is just the background (to show that it's the 3rd page working). I'm not sure why you think the placement is relevant.

Comment: What I'm aiming to achieve is if you put a value in the "Entry" field (like 200). It does get printed on page3 but I want the white space to show that value (like 200).

Comment: thanks for helping but this does not tackle my issue. I'm trying to show the entry widget value on the page3/blue screen. Your advise just places the label. For confirmation, if you you change page3 line 26 to: Label_value = Label(self, text = "value"). Where it says value I'm trying to get the input field's value

Comment: I used this from Page2 to Page3..... `Label_value.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=CENTER)` and `DF2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)`. So I set LIstbox height=10, so  I can  see Label widget.

Comment: yes but i want to get something like this: https://ibb.co/Fb0NS31 (page2), https://ibb.co/gjTKRnc (page3). And in your screenshot I cannot see the input (200) on page3

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're proposing. Can you formulate your changes in a formal answer to the question that gives the result like the picture I sent here (ibb.co/gjTKRnc) including the code you use?

Comment: Anyone who can help me please? :/